# Apply style only on child elements in the first level

Tags: css

```
<ul>
  <li> <span> apply </span> </li>
  <li> <span> apply </span> </li>
  <li> 
    <ul>
      <li> <span> ignore </span> </li>
      <li> <span> ignore </span> </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How can I apply a CSS rule only to span elements from the first level, and make span elements from the nested list ignore the rule?

Can this be done without specifically resetting the properties on the 2nd level spans?

Tried `ul > li span` but it doesn't seem to work, I get the styles applied to 2nd level too

Comment: What element is the parent of the outer `ul`?

Comment: it's a div? why does that matter?

Comment: See my answer. You can use that as the starting point for your selector.

Comment: @Alex It matters because any rule to effect only the first-level children of ul will effect first-level children of every ul element, therefore we would have to specify a parent element of the ul to style, so it is selectable.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Put your list in a wrapping div with an ID, for example `<div id="ul-wrapper">`, and try:

```css
#ul-wrapper > ul > li > span {
    /* my specific CSS */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 #container >  ul > li span { /* - Your CSS Here - */  }
```

Need to specify a container, so that only the first level ul may be selected.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the parent of the outer `ul` isn't another `li`, you can use that as the starting point for your selector (example assuming it's a `div`):

```
div > ul > li span {
    /* Whatever */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ul > li > span {border:solid 1px red;}
li > ul > li > span {border:none 1px red;};
```

Comment: From the question: "Can this be done without specifically resetting the properties on the 2nd level spans?"